# pytest called from python code to TravisCI

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci, blender

I am trying to integrate `pytest` testing into some code used under blender.  Due to the way blender wraps the python I have had to invoke `pytest` from inside some python code that blender calls.

[Calling pytest from Python code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code)

I have successfully set up a test that runs and even asserts correctly once there is a failure.

```
E       assert (1, 0, 1) == (0, 0, 1)
E         At index 0 diff: 1 != 0
E         Use -v to get the full diff
tests/test_pytest.py:11: AssertionError
```

However this result is not percolated back up through blender and back to the TravisCI tool that the test fails so it marks the test as pass. Here is the log from the run that "Passes"

https://travis-ci.org/douglaskastle/blender-fake-addon/builds/476605512

How does one connect the result from the `pytest` from inside the blender code all the way back up to the TravisCI runner?

Answer (score 0):

All that was required is that the pass of failure from `pytest` needed to be escalated to blender, this was as simple as using the value returned from the function and use `sys.exit` to terminate.

```
exit_val = pytest.main(["tests"], plugins=[SetupPlugin("fake_addon")])
sys.exit(exit_val)
```